# How to get two objects next to my off canvas menu button?

Tags: android, html, css

I have an off canvas menu in my header and I want it to be on the left of my title and little logo, but I just don't know how to do it or where to add anything into my CSS anymore since nothing seems to work.
I already tried using float: left; and adjusted the left and right but it's only changing the things inside my menu, not the actual menu-botton and I've been trying for a several hours to get my airplane and title next to it but I just can't seem to get it to work even one bit.

```js
<!-- OFF MENU CANVAS JS-->

function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}

<!-- END OFF MENU CANVAS -->
```

```css
header {
 z-index: 1000;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #5BC2FF;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* OFF CANVAS MENU */
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
 backgound-color: #586166;
}

#airplane {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 100px;
  background: red; /* To illustrate the <img> */
  height: 40px; /* To illustrate the <img> */
  width: 60px; /* To illustrate the <img> */
  text-align: center; /* To illustrate the <img> */
}

#logoheader {
 float: left;
}

.headertext2 {
 z-index: 100;
   text-align: center;
 font-family: "annie-use-your-telescope", "Arial", "sans-serif";
 display: inline;
 float: left;
}

#mySidenav {
 float: left;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #5BC2FF;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron-fluid">
 <header class="fixed-top">
  <!-- OFF CANVAS MENU START -->
 <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">My Journey</a>
  <a href="#">My Account</a>
  <a href="#">Create new account</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>

<div id="main">
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; </span>
  </div>
<!-- OFF CANVAS MENU END -->
 
    <div id="airplane">Logo</div>
    
    <h1 class="headertext2">My Journey</h1>

 </header></div>
```

Comment: you can show your code, your output and desired outputs. With this information how someone can help you?

Comment: Where do you want to place the image and the title? Into the blue menu line?

Comment: @ChiragPatel yeah I accidentally posted before I finished asking my question. Hopefully it's more clear now!

Comment: @DiabloSteve yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need display:inline-block here.
Try to change these 3 class lines:

```
#airplane {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.headertext2 {
    z-index: 100;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "annie-use-your-telescope", "Arial", "sans-serif";
    display: inline;
    display:inline-block;
}

#main {
    transition: .5s;
    padding: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

There is no logoheader id, so you dont need this:

```
#logoheader {
    float: left;
}
```

Update:

If you want to place the image on the right side if the menu is opened, you may define the rightimage class like this:

```
.rightimage{
    float: right;
}
```

And modify the js, which will switch this class on the image:

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    document.getElementById("airplane").classList.add("rightimage");
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
    document.getElementById("airplane").classList.remove("rightimage");
}
```

I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was already really helpful :) Is there a way to make the airplane move to the right when I open the menu too?

Comment: If the menu opens, the image move to the right side of the screen, it should jump to right?

Comment: Never mind. It works now as I forgot to delete some other CSS! Thank you :)

Comment: This right move plan was a bit strange, but I hope my update will be helpful to. :) You are wellcome. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it like this? For the CSS part I added `position: relative;` to the `#main{..}` and `position: absolute; left:80px; top: 15px;` to the logo and `position: absolute; width: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, 0);` to the `.headertext2{..}`

For the html part I moved the `<div id="airplane">` and `<h1 class="headertext2">` inside the `<div id="main"></div>`

Or do you want it to also move to the right with the menu button when opening the menu?

```js
<!-- OFF MENU CANVAS JS-->

function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  document.getElementById("headertext2").style.transform = "translate(99%, 0)";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
  document.getElementById("headertext2").style.transform = "translate(50%, 0)";
}

<!-- END OFF MENU CANVAS -->
```

```css
header {
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #5BC2FF;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* OFF CANVAS MENU */

body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  backgound-color: #586166;
}

#airplane {
  position: absolute;
  left: 80px;
  top: 15px;
  background: red;/* To illustrate the <img> */
  height: 40px;/* To illustrate the <img> */
  width: 60px;/* To illustrate the <img> */
  text-align: center;/* To illustrate the <img> */
}

#logoheader {
  float: left;
}

#headertext2 {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "annie-use-your-telescope", "Arial", "sans-serif";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, 0);
}

#mySidenav {
  float: left;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #5BC2FF;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
  transition: .5s;
  padding: 16px;
  z-index: 101;
  position: relative;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron-fluid">
  <header class="fixed-top">
    <!-- OFF CANVAS MENU START -->
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <a href="#">My Journey</a>
      <a href="#">My Account</a>
      <a href="#">Create new account</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
      <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; </span>
      <div id="airplane">Logo</div>

    <h1 id="headertext2">My Journey</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- OFF CANVAS MENU END -->

  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not a bad but display inline-block is a better way, and the title is not in the header line with this code. 2. point: the position absolute will move the image over the left menu if there will be a z-index later.

Comment: Thank you! I would love it if the airplane could move to the right as well when I open the menu!

Comment: @LindaLeijten I see you got an answer already (which is a bit easier to implement as this one) but I still added this in case you need something else.